# AWS autoscaling an existing instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

This question has a conceptual and practical parts.

Conceptually I'd like to know if using the autoscaling functionality is equivalent to simply increasing the compute power by a factor of the number of added instances?

Practically ... how does this work? I have one running instance, its database sitting on an LVM composed of multiple EBS volumes, similarly with all website data. Judging from the load on the instance I either need to upgrade to a more powerful instance or introduce this autoscaling. Is it a copy of the running server? If so, how is the database (etc) kept consistent?

I've read through the AWS documentation, and still haven't got the picture yet - I could set one autoscaling group up which would probably clear my doubts, but I am very leery to do this with a production server.

Any nudges in the right direction would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally if you have a solution that also uses a database, and several machines in the solution, the database is typically not on any of the machines but is instead hosted seperately with each worker machine pointing to the same database - if you are on AWS platform already, then DynamoDB or RDS are both good solutions for this.

In theory, for some applications, upgrading the size of the single machine will give you the same power as adding several smaller machines, but increasing the size of the single machine, while usually these easiest thing to do at first, should not be considered autoscaling and has its own drawbacks. Here are some things to consider:

- Using multiple machines instead of one big one gives you some fault tolerance. One or more machines can go down and if your solution is properly designed new machines will spin up to replace them.
- Increasing the size of a single machine solution means you are probably paying too much. If you size that single machine big enough to handle peak workloads, that means at other times (maybe most of the time), you are paying for a bigger machine than you need. If you setup your autoscaling solution properly more machines come on line in response to increasing demand, and then they terminate when that demand decreases - you only pay for the power you need when you need it.
- When your solution is designed in this manner, you need to think of all of the worker machines as ephermal - likely to disappear at any time, so you need to build your solution differently. Besides using a hosted database (like on DynamoDB or AWS RDS), you also should not store any data on the machines in your auto-scaling group that doesn't also live somewhere else. For example, if part of your app allows users to upload images, you don't store them on the instances, you store them in S3. Same would apply to any other new data that comes in.

You need to be able to figuratively 'pull the plug' at any instant on any of the machines in your ASG without losing data.

Ultimately a properly setup auto-scaling solution will likely serve you better, but without doubt it is simpler to just 'buy a bigger machine' and the extra money you spend on running that bigger machine may be more than offset by the time and effort you don't have to spend re-architecting your solution to properly run in an autoscaling environment. The unique requirements of your solution will ultimately decide which approach is better.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to do it without RDS or DynamoDB?

Comment: Yes, any database would work, you just don't want the database to live on one of the boxes that will be part of the Auto-scale group.